# MySql exception Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object

Tags: mysql, spring, apache, jdbc, database-connection

I hope you can help me, i am stuck with error on production env...
I am running Spring main application java 1.7 with MySql connector version 5.1.2 and Apache commons connection pool version 1.3.

**My spring data source configuration:**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="1000" />
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

After few hours running, got the exception
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object

At first i thought there is a connection leak , after running netstat to check DB connections i saw every thing is well managed and the amount of connections is well kept as it should be much lower then the maxActive value...

One more strange thing is,in every current moment 3 instances of that main application are running each with differences in  business logic configuration, but the data source configuration is the same in each, the thing is i get the exception only for one instance while the other two are getting connections from DB as usual.

Except from my Java instances which pooling connections from the MySql db there more services which communicates with the DB, but the number of total connections to DB is much lower then in my MySql configuration.

I read related posts regarding that exception, but the mainly the problem was a connection leak but in my case i am pretty sure i ain't got any.

Thanks for your help....

Answer (score 0):

One of your java instance looses connection with database but BasicDataSource handle this problem but as you have specified maxWait property value 1000 so the pool will wait for only 1000 milliseconds for a connection to be returned before throwing an exception either remove that maxwait tag or specify -1 value for indefinete wait.

you should use validationquery property to validate connection from this pool

so your BasicDataSource is missing some configuration so add the below configuration   property your problem will be solved

```
<property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" /> 
<property name="validationQuery"><value>SELECT 1</value></property>
<property name="testOnBorrow"><value>true</value></property>
```

and for more configuration refer to this link http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html